# Extending an existing VSCode syntax highlighter with new elements

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

I am working on a new flavor of Markdown that introduces some new syntactical elements. I have manually modified the `markdown.tmLanguage.json` file bundled with VSCode to implement some syntax highlighting for them. I would now like to create a VSCode extension that provides the new additions to Markdown's syntax highlighting.

However, I do not really think that copy-pasting the original Markdown syntax highlighting logic just to add a few things on top is a good idea -- is there a way to create a `.json` syntax highlighting file that *inherits* (for lack of a better word) the existing syntax highlighting from another file?

For example, here's some pseudocode:

```json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "My Markdown Flavor",
    "extends": "markdown.tmLanguage.json", // <- PSEUDOCODE
    "repository": { "... insert my extensions here ..." }
}
```

Is that possible? Or do I have to copy-paste the entire `markdown.tmLanguage.json` file?

Comment: To whoever voted for closure: the focus of the question is pretty specific and narrow. Please elaborate on your closure vote.

Comment: how often will it happen that a language is a super set of an existing language? Almost never. So it is not part of the syntax of the language file, Write a Node script that builds the final language file by including the Markdown found in your VSC install or the Insiders build to get the latest. Read both JSON files and combine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out -- it is sufficient to include `text.html.markdown` as the last pattern:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
    "name": "Majsdown",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#majsdown_inject_expression"
        },
        {
            "include": "#majsdown_execute_statement"
        },
        {
            "include": "text.html.markdown"
        }
    ],
    
    // ...
```